# How to create a reusable subview with controls, without using xib file

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm coding an app, and have several views that are reused (f. ex. containing a textfield, a label and a button)
Now i would like to just create it in a "globalviews.m" file once and add it as a subview to the mainview. (I really don't like the interface builder)

I could easily create a function that returns a UIView, with the components in them, but i would like to access the controls of course.

I was hoping something like (making "searchview" global in the viewcontroller in use)

```
// making searchview a global thingy
UIView *seachview ;

// rest of code here and then in viewdidload:

UIView *seachview = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
searchview = [[globaviews alloc] thesearchviews_name] ;
[self addsubview:searchview] ;
```

But how could I make controls inside easily accessible. Like:

```
NSString *something = searchview.textviewname.text ;
```

Or would this be a terrible idea to begin with?
Its just the way I would prefer to code...

Comment: don't forget to mark top answer and upvote answers that have solved your issue. If no answer has then leave comments or edit your question to provide more detail. People facing the same issue will wat=nt to know what solved your question. Leaving this question open like this doesn't help anybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom class that is a subclass of `UIView`. You could then add properties for each control (the same way you would add `NSString`, `NSNumber` etc). Or you could create public methods to modify / get data.

e.g.

```
- (void)setTextFiledColour:(UIColor *)color;
- (NSString *)getTextFieldText;
```

My personal opinion (from a lot of experience) is to learn interface builder and deal with it. It is perfectly possible to do what you want and many people agree with you and choose to do it that way. Personally I've never seen it done "right". Meaning that its all done custom to create their own patterns and methodologies, avoiding years of experience and testing that has gone into the patterns provided by interface builder.

I find that storyboards in particular force a very specific pattern and style of coding. I think moving away form that is a huge mistake, as if used correctly it has great potential to abstract away UI / Code, prevents taking shortcuts that come back later on and most importantly when someone else needs to change it, there is no ambiguity, you can't make a mistake with class names or variable names etc.

I've used storyboards a lot and have yet to have an issue with them, on the flip side i've worked with developers who insist on doing it all by hand and have never had so many issues, and shocked at how long it takes to develop applications in this manner.

In the end its up to you.

**Note**

You mentioned wanting to create a view and reuse it. Its also possible to do this in a .xib file and reuse it that way. Losing some of the storyboard abilities but might give you a little of both worlds.

Comment: I decided to go with the xib file instead. It seems to be the easiest way, and also the way I'm "supposed to".
To me storyboards is very new, so i actually don't use it at all.
But thanks for your input.